# How to version string elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have below list of strings available as list

```
 List<string> available = new List<string> {"C1,C2,C3,C1_V1" };
```

I have input parameter C1. Now I have to match available strings in available list of strings. Whenever my input is C1 then matching elements are C1,C1_V1 in available so my string should increase by 1 to get C1_v2. I have mentioned clearly in below table

[image]

As per the above table,

case 1- Avail is C1,C2,C3 and input is C1 so my destination should be C1_V1
case 2 - avail is C1,C2,C3,C1_V1 and input is C1 but my destination cannot be C1_v1 because it is already available in avail so next version should be C1_v2 and so on.

I am trying to implement this logic in c#. I have started doing this but couldnt get it done

```
List<string> available = new List<string> {"C1,C2,C3,C1_V1" };

string input = "C1";

string destination = string.Empty;

foreach(var data in available)
{
    destination = $"{input}_V{initialVersion}";
}
```

Can someone help me to complete this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like "source" is your primary key but you have same value for more than 1 row.  You need to determine what your primary key is here.  You can't pass in c1 and magically have the code know what destination to pull out as there are 2 rows with c1 as source.

Comment: Hi Aikl, I am just giving scenarios in table. At a time only one row is considered

Comment: What are you using to access your table.  LINQ/SQL?

Comment: Yes Linq.........

Comment: Could do something like var sources = DBContext.Sources.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.source=="c1");  This would return your single row as it will only match by c1 value and you said this will be unique.  Then you will have avail and destination in your object to do with what you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count the number of items in `available` that match the given input, and use that count to determine the version.

A simple matching algorithm might be where a `string` in `available` is equal to `input` or where a `string` in `available` starts with `"{input}_"`.

In order to handle cases where `input` is given with the version part, such as `C1_V1` you need to split the `input` on the version separator, `'_'`, and just look at the "key" part of the `input`.

```
public string NextVersion(string input, List<string> available)
{
    // Argument validation omitted.
    if (input.Contains('_'))
    {
        input = input.Split('_')[0];
    }
    int count = available.Count(a => string.Equals(a, input) || a.StartsWith($"{input}_"));
    if (count == 0)
    {
        // The given input doesn't exist in available, so we can just return it as
        // the "next version".
        return input;
    }

    // Otherwise, the next version is the count of items that we found.
    return $"{input}_V{count}";
}
```

This assumes that `'_'` is only valid as a version separator. If you can have `string`s in `available` such as `"C1_AUX"` then you'll run into issues trying to get the next version of `"C1"`.

It also assumes that you want to increment to the next version, even if `input` is a version that doesn't exist. For example, if `available` is `["C1", "C1_V1"]` and `input` is `"C1_V123"` than the return value should be `"C1_V2"`.

Poul Bak raises another caveat. If you end up with a situation where `available` is missing a version. For example, if `available` is `["C1", "C1_V2"]` and `input` is `"C1"` then the result of this function is `"C1_V2"`, leading to a duplicate version. In this case, you'd probably have to find every item in `available` where the "key" part is `input`'s key part, then parse each one to find the next version.

It isn't clear what the constraints are requirements are exactly, so these caveats may or may not be an issue. But they're certainly worth keeping in mind.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I tested this code but In 3rd scenario as mentioned in the table it is returning C1_V1_V1 but I am expecting C1_V3

Comment: You can check `input` for the version separator (`_`) then split it on that and just take the first item in the array. That way you're only dealing with the "Key" part of the string. I've edited the answer.

Comment: "*You could count the number of items in available*". Careful, what if an item in the middle is later deleted?

Comment: @joshuaRobison I need one help in the above code. for example if the input string is kishore_duplicatedrequested then it should generate kishore_duplicatedrequested_v1. How we can achive using above code.